# Transition matrix from Basis $B$ to $B_0.$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a basis $B_0 = \{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ and basis $B = \{u_1,u_2,u_3\}$ of the space $E=\mathbb{R}^{3}$ what is the transition matrix from $B$ to $B_0?$

As far as I recall the transition matrix from $B$ to $B_0$ is defined as follows: 
$$Q = \begin{bmatrix}
 [u_1]_{B_0}& [u_2]_{B_0} && [u_3]_{B_0}\\ 
\end{bmatrix}.$$
In other words writing the each $u_1$ in the basis $B_0.$ However, I am working on this exercise in French where the questions asks:

> En déduire la matrice de passage $Q$ de $B$ à $B_0$.

which translates to asking for the transition matrix. The answer given in the correction of the exercise is

$$Q = \begin{bmatrix}
 [e_1]_{B}& [e_2]_{B} && [e_3]_{B}\\ 
\end{bmatrix}.$$

I am thus confused, perhaps someone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it's due to definitions being different in French and in English: The « matrice de passage de $B$ à $B_0$ » is equal to the “transition matrix from $B_0$ to $B$”, *with inverted source and destination*, because:

- the French « matrice de passage de $B$ à $B_0$ » $Q_{B \to B_0}^{Fr}$ is the matrix describing how basis $B = (u_1, u_2, u_3)$ is transformed into basis $B_0 = (e_1, e_2, e_3)$, thus, in other words, how vectors $(e_i)$ are expressed in terms of vectors $(u_i)$: $Q_{B \to B_0}^{Fr} \overset{def}{=} \begin{bmatrix} [e_1]_B & [e_2]_B & [e_3]_B \end{bmatrix}$
- the English “transition matrix from $B$ to $B_0$” $Q_{En}$ is the matrix telling how components of an arbitrary vector $V$ expressed in basis $B$ are transformed into components expressed in basis $B_0$: $\forall V, Q_{B \to B_0}^{En} \, [V]_B \overset{def}{=} [V]_{B_0}$, hence $Q_{B \to B_0}^{En} = \begin{bmatrix} [u_1]_{B_0} & [u_2]_{B_0} & [u_3]_{B_0} \end{bmatrix}$

Proof:

- $B \, Q_{B \to B_0}^{Fr} = B_0$ follows immediately from definition of $Q_{B \to B_0}^{Fr}$
- so $\forall V, B \, [V]_B = V = B_0 \, [V]_{B_0} = B \, Q_{B \to B_0}^{Fr} \, Q_{B \to B_0}^{En} \, [V]_B$
- $B$ is a basis, so by uniqueness of decomposition we have $\forall V, [V]_B = Q_{B \to B_0}^{Fr} \, Q_{B \to B_0}^{En} \, [V]_B$
- as the relation stands $\forall V$ we thus deduce $Q_{B \to B_0}^{Fr} \, Q_{B \to B_0}^{En} = I$, hence $Q_{B \to B_0}^{En} = {Q_{B \to B_0}^{Fr}}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} [u_1]_{B_0} & [u_2]_{B_0} & [u_3]_{B_0} \end{bmatrix}$
- thus $Q_{B \to B_0}^{Fr} = {Q_{B \to B_0}^{En}}^{-1} = Q_{B_0 \to B}^{En}$

So, depending on what is transformed into what (the basis or the components of an arbitrary vector), the definitions of « matrice de passage » and “transition matrix” are inverted.

It's not the only example where French and English definitions are different, to my great sorrow (I think maths in French but my paper (in progress for years) is of course in English), here are some other examples I've noticed (there are probably a lot more which I'm not aware of):

- “positive” vs. « positif »:

  - “positive” means $> 0$ and “negative” means $< 0$; $\ge 0$ is “non-negative” and $\le 0$ is “non-positive”
  - « positif » means $\ge 0$ and « négatif » means $\le 0$; $> 0$ is « strictement positif » and $< 0$ is « strictement négatif »
- “field” vs. « corps »: a “field” is a « corps commutatif » while a « corps » is a “division ring” (or a “skew field”); A lot of other algebraic structure names have the same translation issue between French and English, depending on whether some property (commutativity, unitarity, etc.) is implicitly attached to the definition of the structure or not